# Disable submit button when textarea added dynamically is empty - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable a submit button if any textarea is empty. It works fine if the area is static. But if I add another text area by clicking a button, it will work only when I click inside the dynamically added textarea.

I have tried using all sorts of events (input click keyup keypress blur keyup), but still the result is the same.

Here is my code

```
<div class='form'>
   <textarea name="answer[]" id="answer" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Type your answer here"></textarea>
   <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" id="insert"/>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <button class="btn btn-info add_field_button">Add Another textarea</button>
   <div class="input_fields_wrap form-group">
   </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click

        e.preventDefault();

        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment

            $(wrapper).append('<textarea name="answer[]" id="answer" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Type your answer here"></textarea><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove_field">Delete</button></div>');


        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('input click keyup keypress blur keyup', 'textarea', function () {

        var empty = false;
        $('textarea').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Should I somehow fire the function checking if any textarea is empty on the button that adds new textarea?

Here is Demo in **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/largan/w9duLaby/19/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add new `textarea` under `click` event there only check if the textarea is empty or not and depending on this disabled or enabled button.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click

    e.preventDefault();

    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
    //added <div>
      $(wrapper).append('<div><textarea name="answer[]" id="answer" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Type your answer here"></textarea><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove_field">Delete</button></div>');


    }
    //chcking added textrea is empty
    $('textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        //disable
        $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        //enabled
        $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
      }
    });


  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
       //chcking added textrea is empty
    $('textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        //disable
        $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        //enabled
        $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  })
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('input click keyup keypress blur keyup', 'textarea', function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        empty = true;
      }
    });

    if (empty) {
      $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <textarea name="answer[]" id="answer" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Type your answer here"></textarea>
  <div class='actions'>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" id="insert" />
  </div>
  <hr>
  <button class="btn btn-info add_field_button">Add Another textarea</button>
  <div class="input_fields_wrap form-group">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I was so close. I have tried that as well, but added it inside the `if (x < max_fields)`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Same you need to do on delete button because if the textarea is empty the button will be disable , so if you delete the `empty` textarea then still button will be disable to avoid this again check all textarea .Now, to minimize code you can put the checking part in some function and call the same when needed.